# Laptop ethernet port blinks once when plugging in power

Tags: ethernet, power

Weird question. On my Acer Aspire 5750, when the machine is powered off and I plug in the power cord the ethernet port (located right next to the power jack) blinks green once. This does not happen if plugging in the power while the machine is turned on. The blink happens immediately as the power plug is inserted.

Is this something to be worried about? The laptop seems to work fine otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may well be a feature.

The port activity LED flashes when it is first powered up to let you know that the port is getting power. If the computer is already turned on (i.e. running on batteries) plugging in the transformer doesn't change the Ethernet port's power status, so no flash.

Comment: Interesting. Have you seen this behavior on laptops before?

Comment: I've seen the blink-on-powerup behavior of a variety of devices. I've never watched the ports on a laptop closely enough to report if it does or does not do what you describe, but it makes a certain kind of sense so it might be what's going on.